# Spring-boot-starter-activemq 3.0.0-M1 not found in the milestone repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

Even though the spring-boot-dependencies-3.0.0-M1.pom lists the spring-boot-starter-activemq-3.0.0-M1 as a dependency, spring-boot-starter-activemq-3.0.0-M1 is not available in https://repo.spring.io/milestone.

Comment: That is probably by accident. ActiveMQ support has been removed as that isn't available in a JakartaEE version. You should use the Artemis starter instead.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably by accident. ActiveMQ support has been removed as that isn't available in a JakartaEE version. You should use the Artemis starter instead.

This is also explained in [the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#removed-support).

Finally remember it is "just" a milestone release NOT a final release (which is expected somewhere around the end of 2022).

Comment: Denium
I'm having problems migrating my project to spring boot 3.0.0. I added artemis instead of  the old activeMQ. I changed lots of packages in my code from javax to jakarta. However I'm having problems, that artemis 27.0 is using javax.jms itself for javax.jms.TextMessage parent of ACtiveMQTextMessage. This is causing compilation error for me

Comment: Don't hijack comments to ask a question, as a proper question in stead. You should only bring in the starter don't manage dependencies on artemis yourself (which probably pulls in the old API).